# Mail "proxy" to add encrypted authentication support for legacy programs

Tags: proxy, smtp, encryption

There are some programs that my company use that do not support encrypted smtp authentication and using unencrypted auth is not possible (hosted on the internet by another provider, they will not lower the security)

These programs send from numerous **valid** mail accounts and do not receive mail, they can do normal smtp auth.

is there a program or way to add an in between service to add encryption?

The mail must be sent through the hosted mail server to avoid being removed by spam filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using http://www.stunnel.org/ to add SSL to the SMTP

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to relay the various programs through one of your SMTP servers that does support encrypted requirements.